# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rspec

I some problems with my tests after adding a custom validation to the income model.

```
@member.incomes << [Income.new(starting_date: '2015-01-01', amount: 1200, member: @member), 
                    Income.new(starting_date: '2015-04-01', amount: 1400, member: @member)]
```

I get the following error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

My observation with the `debugger`:
the first record is correctly inserted, but the 2nd one is getting the error.

What I'm doing wrong - any idea?

UPDATE:
the concat method couldn't help here.

more code:

```
income.rb
validate :newly_added_income_is_also_the_newest?
....
..
def newly_added_income_is_also_the_newest?
  latest_income = Income.where(member: member_id).select{|i|i}.max(&:starting_date)
  return true if latest_income.nil?
  if !latest_income.nil? && latest_income.starting_date >= starting_date
    errors.add(:income, "newest income should be also the latest income of the member '#{member.full_name}''")
  end
end
```

#### test: [Budget] should get all incomes which are in between of the start_date and end_date

```
@member.incomes.concat[Income.new(starting_date: '2015-01-01', amount: 1200, member: @member),
                            Income.new(starting_date: '2015-04-01', amount: 1400, member: @member)]
     budget = FactoryGirl.create(:budget, donation: @donation, member: @member)
     expect(budget.get_all_incomes_for_budget_duration.size).to eq(3)
```

***log1***

```
    1) Budget Tests with a budget based donation types [Budget] should get all incomes which are in between of the start_date and end_date
         Failure/Error: @member.incomes.concat[Income.new(starting_date: '2015-01-01', amount: 1200, member: @member),
         TypeError:
           no implicit conversion of Income into Integer
         # ./spec/models/budget_spec.rb:44:in `[]'
         # ./spec/models/budget_spec.rb:44:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

#### test2: [Budget] should get an adapted promise for income change between the budget range (FAILED - 2)

```
it '[Budget] should get an adapted promise for income change between the budget range', skip_before: true do
   Member.delete_all
   Donation.delete_all
   member = FactoryGirl.create(:member)
   donation = FactoryGirl.create(:majlis_khuddam_donation)
   #income = FactoryGirl.create(:income, member: member)

   member.incomes << Income.new(starting_date: '2015-01-01', amount: 1200, member_id: 12345) <<
       Income.new(starting_date: '2015-03-01', amount: 1000, member_id: 12345)

   budget = FactoryGirl.create(:budget, donation: donation, member: member)

   expect(budget.promise).to eq(123)
 end
```

***log2***

```
  2) Budget Tests with a budget based donation types [Budget] should get an adapted promise for income change between the budget range
       Failure/Error: Income.new(starting_date: '2015-03-01', amount: 1000, member_id: 12345)
       ArgumentError:
         wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
       # /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@maalify/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:48:in `__temp__374716274796e676f546164756'
       # ./app/models/income.rb:22:in `each'
       # ./app/models/income.rb:22:in `max'
       # ./app/models/income.rb:22:in `newly_added_income_is_also_the_newest?'
```

Comment: Would not `@member.incomes << Income.new(...) << Income.new(...)` solve an issue? Anyway, please post the whole error message, especially the method name.

Comment: You need to show what method is raising the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error occurs here:

```
latest_income = Income.where(member: member_id).select{|i|i}.max(&:starting_date)
```

`max` is a method defined in `Enumerable`. It does not take an argument, thus the message "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)".

You probably want the method `maximum`, which is defined in ActiveRecord. It takes a column name:

```
latest_income = Income.where(member: member_id).maximum(:starting_date)
```

Comment: GREAT +1 that's it!  I'm know using the recommended `maximum` method from ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

The `<<` is a shorthand for `push`, but i think in this case you want to achieve either (as @mudasobwa said)

```
@member.incomes << Income.new(...) << Income.new(...)
```

which pushes both new instances individually, or try

```
@member.incomes.concat [Income.new(...), Income.new(...)]
```

if you want to 'merge' two arrays

Comment: it didn't solve the problem, I have added more code @mudasobwa